# iterm2 default window size

Tags: iterm

I'm trying to find a place where to set the default window size on newly created windows.

In iterm1 there was display profiles, which I do not see iterm2.         http://iterm.sourceforge.net/usage.shtml

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You have to specify the default window size in rows and columns. The setting can be found in iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Window.

Comment: I found that after disconnecting a second monitor that iTerm2 did not resize it's window until I went into the Preferences like this.  Thanks!

Comment: Specifying a column or row amount larger than your screen will allow makes the iTerm as wide and tall as it can be, but will not go outside the screen. (So if you're wondering what values will make a full-screen window, 500 in both directions should do the trick if you don't feel like experimenting.)

Comment: For those who were wondering how to get current window size in rows and columns:
Just pull the window by the edge to resize it a bit — current size will appear in the window title.

Comment: In my case using this trick the window does indeed go outside of the screen

Comment: MacOS Ventura+: iTerm > Settings > Profiles > Window

Comment: The limit column size seems to be 208, how to go higher?

Answer (score 22):

Here is the screen you can set up the size of the window

```
iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Window > Settings for New Windows
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Once you have made the changes in Profile => Window make sure that

```
Disable session-initiated window resizing
```

is unchecked for your changes to take effect in default iterm window

and then restart item

Comment: What does this even do? It had no obvious effect for me. Also, for those wondering where to find this:
`iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Disable session-initiated window resizing`